# Batch export with empty name

Tags: python, scripting

[image]
I am curious about how to batch export multiple models in the photo above with each EMPTY title as a script.

Comment: did u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each object in `bpy.data.objects` and check if the type is `EMPTY`. You can then get the child object and export it as an `obj` file. Using your example, the following script will export two `obj` files within the same directory as the currently saved blender file. So make sure the blender file is saved. The names of the `obj` files will use the *empty* objects' names ***Terrain 52SCF5661.obj*** and ***Terrain 52SCF5662.obj***

```
import bpy
import os

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

def getChildren(obj):
    children = [] 
    for o in bpy.data.objects: 
        if o.parent == obj: 
            children.append(o) 
    return children

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if not o.type == 'EMPTY':
        continue

    children = getChildren(o)
    if len(children) <= 0:
        continue

    mesh = children[0]
    mesh.select_set(True)

    directory = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
    filepath = os.path.join(directory, o.name + ".obj")
    bpy.ops.wm.obj_export(filepath=filepath, export_selected_objects=True)
    mesh.select_set(False)
```